# Magento Web Service Errors

Tags: c#, .net, soap, magento, xml-rpc

I am implementing a custom solution to interface with a [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com) website. My code is in C#. I am trying to create products using either the `v2_soap API` and the `xml-rpc API` web services. I have attempted to create a product using both services. I cannot seem to successfully create a product. With each service I receive the error message  `[102] Invalid data given. Details in error message.`. I have tried passing in a variety of data to the api call, but have not had any luck. I am wondering a few things:

1) Is there any way to recieve better error messages about what data is not valid when I make a web service call? The error message seems to indicate that I can get `details` somewhere, but I have searched through all logs, error message data I can find with no luck.

2) What are the minimum attributes required to add a new product using the web service?

Here is a bit of the code I am using. This is the `XML-RPC` implementation. I am using the cook computing xml-rpc library.

```
public int CreateProduct(Product product) {
    var entity = ConvertProduct(product);
    //int productId = Service.catalogProductCreate(SessionId, "simple", "0", product.Sku, entity);
    int productId = XmlRpcService.CallReturnInt(SessionId, "catalog_product.create",
      new object[] { 
         "simple" /* product type */, 
         0 /* attribute set */, 
         product.Sku /* sku */, 
         entity /* product data */ 
      });
    return productId;
}
private XmlRpcStruct ConvertProduct(Product product) {
    var entity = new XmlRpcStruct();
    entity.Add("name", product.Name);
    entity.Add("description", product.Description);
    return entity;
}
protected IMagentoXmlRcpService XmlRpcService {
    get {
        return this.xmlRpcService;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key was the attribute set. The default attribute set is 4 (at least for me). That little guy is the root of a lot of problems. The error responses on the Magento web services could really use some work.

See this forum thread for more info: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/36892/